# Using LIKE %% in query clause with multiple values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a basic query that fetches values from three tables.  The three tables : company, classes_by_company, and person. I have a foreign key in all tables with the name company_id.   In the where clause I am using `LIKE` to compare with a random value the values fetched for any results that may have a match. But I am having no success in doing so. I get an error in the sql line `WHERE a.id LIKE %1% OR a.company_id LIKE %3% OR c.count LIKE %1% OR p.count LIKE %1%`. How can I compare all the values fetched from these three tables against a random value to see if there is a match? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803440/15)

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, a.status,
       c.count AS classes_per_company,
       p.count AS employees_per_company
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM classes_by_company
           GROUP BY company_id) c
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM person
           GROUP BY company_id) p
       ON a.company_id = p.company_id
WHERE a.id LIKE %1% OR a.company_id LIKE %3% OR c.count LIKE %1% OR p.count LIKE %1%
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE company
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     company_id int,
     status varchar(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE classes_by_company
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 company_id int,
 class_name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE person
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
employee_id int,
 company_id int,
 person_name varchar(20)
);
```

Comment: Try: '%1%'  and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` has to be followed by a string, so it should be:

```
WHERE a.id LIKE '%1%'
   OR a.company_id LIKE '%3%'
   OR c.count LIKE '%1%'
   OR p.count LIKE '%1%'
```

Comment: Oh silly me! I overlooked at this important detail thinking it was an `integer`.

Comment: It seems strange that you're using `LIKE` for ID fields. `%1%` will match 1, 10, 11, ..., 19, 21, 31, 41, ..., 100, 210, etc.

Comment: It was just for the example. If there were dates would it be alright?

Comment: Well, it seem strange for dates, too -- why would you want to match a number that might be in the day, month, or year? `LIKE` is usually used to look for words in strings.

Comment: You could do `date LIKE '2013-%', but that would be better written as `YEAR(date) = 2013`.

Answer (score 0):

id is an integer column; the LIKE operator relies on a text data type e.g. nvarchar.

You could convert the id to a string e.g. WHERE CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE '%1%' ...

Please also note the single quotes around the %1%.

Comment: MySQL will automatically convert to strings when necessary, I don't think the cast is needed.

Comment: Good point!  I don't know MySQL too well but your assertion holds true for SQL Server / T-SQL.  Therefore, the only issue is adding the single quotes to the LIKE expression as per your answer.